# SQL SELECT ... IN(xQuery)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

My first xQuery, may be a bit basic, but it's the only time I need to use it at the moment)

```
DECLARE @IdList XML;

SET @IdList =
'<Ids>
    <Id>6faf5db8-b434-437f-99c8-70299f82dab4</Id>
    <Id>5b3ddaf1-3412-471a-a6cf-71f8e1c31168</Id>
    <Id>1da6136d-2ff5-44cc-8510-4713451aac4d</Id>
</Ids>';
```

What I want to do is:

```
SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Id] IN ( /* This list of Id's in the XML */ );
```

What is the desired way to do this?

Note:  The format of the XML (passed into a Stored Procedure from C#) is also under my control, so if there is a better structure (for performance), then please include details.

Also, there could be 1000's of Id's in the real list if that makes a difference..

Thanks
Rob

Comment: what sql platform? ms-sql?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008R2 (Version 10.50.2550)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing 1000's of Id's, I don't think this will be a stellar performer, but give it a try:

```
    DECLARE @IdList XML;

    SET @IdList =
    '<Ids>
        <Id>6faf5db8-b434-437f-99c8-70299f82dab4</Id>
        <Id>5b3ddaf1-3412-471a-a6cf-71f8e1c31168</Id>
        <Id>1da6136d-2ff5-44cc-8510-4713451aac4d</Id>       
    </Ids>';

    select * from mytable where id in
    (
        select cast(T.c.query('text()') as varchar(36)) as result  from @idlist.nodes('/Ids/Id') as T(c)
)
```

You might look at table valued parameters as a better way, unless you already have your data in XML.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It works and answers my question.  But I had not considered Table valued parameters.  As I have control over that too, I will check that out.  I agree with you that the performance and readability of the code will be better.